# Finding the maximum likelihood estimator of theta

Tags: parameter-estimation

The question reads : Find the maximum likelihood estimator for theta based on the sample of size n from a distribution with density $$f(x|\theta)=\frac{2\theta^2}{x^3};x>\theta.$$
According to my calculations it is observed that the maximum is not attained at a critical point, however I thought it fit to assume theta to be more than zero but not very much sure whether my conclusion will be nice that way.

$$L(\theta)=2n\ln(\theta)+n\ln2-3(\sum \ln(x))$$

$L'(\theta)=\frac{2}{\theta}$ which maximizes the the pdf but I am finding it difficult to conclude from the derivative with respect to theta.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your question tho? To validate your result?

Comment: What is the best way of concluding on the properties of estimators that lead to such result,.

Comment: The loglikelihood `L` is increasing hence one wants to choose `theta` as large as possible. But "as large as possible" here is severely restricted by the condition that `x>theta` for every `x` in the sample, otherwise `L=-oo`. Thus the MLE is `hat-theta=min x`.

Comment: @Did Thank you very much for your effort,its not that easy to get such a friendly response

Comment: @Did somewhat of a pedantic point here, but if $\hat\theta = \min_i x_i$ then $\hat\theta=x_j$ for some $j$, and so we don't have $x_i>\theta$ for all $i$. So I amended my answer to use $\geqslant$ instead - no harm since this is an absolutely continuous distribution.

Comment: @Math1000 Indeed, there might not be any MLE but a "supremum likelihood estimate", so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on on @Did's comment, we find that
$$\frac\partial{\partial \theta}\ell(\theta)=\frac{2n}\theta>0$$
for all $\theta$. Hence the MLE is $$\operatorname{argmax}_\theta \ell(\theta) = \max\{\theta : x_i \geqslant \theta\; \forall i\}=\min_i x_i. $$